# Who do IGBT rectifiers have floating gates (unlike MOSFET rectifiers)?

Tags: transistors, rectifier, fet, igbt, floating

When I search Google Images for "IGBT rectifier", I notice that they all appear to have floating gates.

[image]

But don't IGBT's have gates like the ones on MOSFET's, in which it's insulated from the other pins on the transistor?  How do they work without an input to control the gate voltage?  Wouldn't this be terribly sensitive to the environment.
Why don't these rectifiers have gates connected similarly to the ones in MOSFET rectifiers like the one below.

[image]

On the side note, I also notice that the IGBT rectifiers all seem to be 3-phase.

Comment: They are not floating.  Six control lines are associated with them.  They are left off for clarity because they are electronics, not power.  Electronics is magic to power types.

Comment: There's no such a thing likr IGBT rectifier.  First there are no P channel IGBTs but also they do have a few volts Vce(sat) at high currents. So you'd loose  the loss reductionc you have with MOSFETs. Nonetheless the three phase IGBT bridge can actually be also used as rectifier or bi-directional converter when driven as a buck-boost